# Python cursor.execute() return (0,'')

Tags: python, flask

I am using python cursor.execute() for select query in flask, it gives proper result initially but after some time it is throwing (0,''). Any suggestion how to debug this problem ?

```
def query(self, query, params=None, just_data=None, cursor=None):
    result = []
    try:
        print query
        if cursor is None:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        print cursor
        cursor.execute(query, params) if params is not None else cursor.execute(query)
        print cursor.rowcount
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if just_data is not None:
            return result
        else:
            return {"success": True, "data": result}
    except Exception as e:
        if isinstance(e, OperationalError):
            print('Connection timed out. Retrying...')
            cursor.execute(query, params) if params is not None else cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if just_data is not None:
                return result
            else:
                return {"success": True, "data": result}
        else:
            print e.message;
            return jsonify({"success": False, "error": "Error Occurred while querying | " + str(e.message)})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

Regards

Comment: Give your code.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: I would suggest using an IDE (for example PyCharm might be a good place to start, or any other would suffice). Add a breakpoint around that method and debug. Share your findings (stack trace, etc.) here if it is still not obvious of the issue is.

Comment: What are the values for query and params when this happens?

Comment: Params are NONE and query is simple select statement to fetch data from table